# How to convert a 2 d list to map of comma separated 2d list using stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to convert a 2 D list as follows:

```
["A", "1"]
["B", "2"]
["A", "3"]
["A", "4"]
["A", "7"]
["B", "3"]
["B", "1"]
```

I want to convert this list using stream API as follows:

```
["A", ["1", "3", "4", "7"]]
["B", ["2", "3", "1"]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do note that the expected output you give is a list with different type of elements. The 1st element is a String, the 2nd is a *list* of Strings.

Comment: I had to apply stream api 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

- Stream the lists.
- Group by the first element in each list.

```
List<List<String>> lists =List.of(List.of("A", "1"),
        List.of("B", "2"),
        List.of("A", "3"),
        List.of("A", "4"),
        List.of("A", "7"),
        List.of("B", "3"),
        List.of("B", "1"));
 Map<String,List<String>> map = 
               lists.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(lst->lst.get(0),
                     Collectors.mapping(lst->lst.get(1), 
                             Collectors.toList())));
```

Prints

```
A=[1, 3, 4, 7]
B=[2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    var input = List.of(
            List.of("A", "1"),
            List.of("B", "2"),
            List.of("A", "3"),
            List.of("A", "4"),
            List.of("A", "7"),
            List.of("B", "3"),
            List.of("B", "1"));

    var output = input.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(list -> list.get(0), Collectors.mapping(list -> list.get(1), Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println(output);
```

which results in:

```
{A=[1, 3, 4, 7], B=[2, 3, 1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Th answer below doesn't use `stream` API. But, it's good to know more ways to do it.

Java 8 added a new method in `Map` to help with such situations:

```java
List<List<String>> input = List.of(
            List.of("A", "1"),
            List.of("B", "2"),
            List.of("A", "3"),
            List.of("A", "4"),
            List.of("A", "7"),
            List.of("B", "3"),
            List.of("B", "1"));

Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

input.forEach(l -> map.computeIfAbsent(
                         l.get(0), 
                         dummy -> new ArrayList<String>()).add(l.get(1)));

System.out.println(map);

// {A=[1, 3, 4, 7], B=[2, 3, 1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I combined the answers and created one line answer as follows:

List<List> output = input.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o->(String)o.get(0), Collectors.mapping(o->(String)o.get(0), Collectors.toList())))).entrySet().stream()
.map(e->Arrays.asList(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))).collect(Collectors.toList());